# Erro ao enviar uma rota para o mesmo api/Controller/Action em uma WebApi

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Estou tendo o seguinte erro, efetuo a seguinte operação:

```
        // POST: api/Funcionario/AddFuncionario
    [HttpPost("AddFuncionario")]
    public IActionResult AddFuncionario([FromBody] Funcionario Func)
    {
        if(Func == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        funcionarioRepository.AddFuncionario(Func);
        return CreatedAtRoute("BuscarPorId/{id}", new { id = Func.Id }, Func);

    }
```

só que, no meu retorno CreatedAtRoute, a action BuscarPorId não está sendo encontrada, aparece o seguinte erro: *InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.*

Segue minha Action da Api:

```
        [HttpGet("BuscarPorId/{id}")]
    public IActionResult BuscarPorId(int id)
    {
        var item = funcionarioRepository.BuscarPorFuncionario(id);
        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }
```

Comment: Pronto, fiz o seguinte, dei nome a minha request: [HttpGet("BuscarPorId/{id}", Name = "BuscarPorId")]

 e no return createdAtroute ficou assim:
 return CreatedAtRoute("BuscarPorId", new { id = Func.Id }, Func);

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa nomear a rota, o **`CreatedAtRoute`** busca uma rota **pelo nome** e não pelo "*template*" dela.

```
[HttpGet("BuscarPorId/{id}", Name = "NomeDaRota")]
public IActionResult BuscarPorId(int id) { }
```

```
public IActionResult AddFuncionario([FromBody] Funcionario Func)
{
    // (...)
    return CreatedAtRoute("NomeDaRota", new { id = Func.Id }, Func);
}
```